# WPF Button Style with roundend corners relative to the button size and colored line

Tags: wpf, button, wpf-style

I need help making a button looking like this:

[image]

It should have those rounded corners, no matter what the size of the button.

What I have so far:

A style for the Button in the App.xaml

```
<!-- Standard Button Colors-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonBackground" Color="#1C536F" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonForeground" Color="#FEFEFE" />

<!-- Standard Button Template-->
<Style x:Key="StandardButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonForeground}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="55" Background="{StaticResource StandardButtonBackground}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Used in the view:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource StandardButton}" Content="Test" FontSize="20"/>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But the corners are in pixel-size, so when the size of the button changes, the corners do not accordingly.

And next thing is this colored line which should show a status. How can I add such a line?

Comment: Provided the width and height of the button, can you provide the formula to calculate the radius? Radius r = f(w, h)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a converter to get the radius and a second border for the highlight.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window 

    ...

    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Converter -->
        <local:HeightToRadiusConverter x:Key="HeightToRadiusConverter"/>
        <!-- Standard Button Colors-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonBackground" Color="#1C536F" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonForeground" Color="#FEFEFE" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonHighlight" Color="GreenYellow" />
        <!-- Standard Button Template-->
        <Style x:Key="StandardButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource HeightToRadiusConverter}}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource StandardButtonHighlight}"
                                CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource HeightToRadiusConverter}}">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource StandardButton}" Content="Test" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Converter**

```
public class HeightToRadiusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double height = (double)value;
        return height / 2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Resizing the window will resize the button accordingly.